# How can I add custom icons to Oro frontstore menu item?

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I want to display custom icons for menu items in front store of Oro application. I know, there is a way to choose icon from the dropdown list of fontawesome icons in admin panel:

[image]

But can I add my own icon to this list, or set svg or icomoon icon in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only font-awesome icons available out of the box. You can add a custom icon by customizing the template that is used for menu rendering.

To customize the template, please follow [the OroCommerce back-office customization documentation](https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/back-office/templates/).

Pay attention, that customization done differently for [the OroCommerce storefront templates](https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/storefront/templates/).